# How to merge audio and video streams with Popen pipes

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I need to merge two different sources, one has video, the other has audio. None of them are local files, data arrives via websocket blob.

I have a Popen process for ffmpeg like this in Python

```
ffmpeg_process = Popen('/root/bin/ffmpeg -i - -i -  -f flv out.flv, shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
```

I'm aware that sending video to the first `-i` works like this:

```
ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(data)
```

So my question is, how do I send audio data to the second `-i` param via the stdin pipe?

Comment: What's wrong with writing first the video in a temp file, then muxing in the audio in a second call?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that but my client who is a developer too has that requirement, to only use pipes to avoid files.

Comment: Well, I imagine you can do it fully through pipes using two processes - start the video building first and write output to stdout, then redirect that stdout to stdin of the next call used to add the audio to produce the final file. It's a silly and unreasonable request, but if you insist....